# State is not working as it supposed to react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm mapping array like this:

```
   {activeNewsCategories.map((i) => (
                <Tags
                  key={i}
                  tagName={i}
                  getNewsByCategory={getNewsByCategory}
                />
              ))}
```

This is inside of Tags component:

```
 const Tags = ({tagName, getNewsByCategory}) => {
  const [selectedCategory, chooseCategory] = useState(false);

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={
        selectedCategory
          ? styles.chosenActiveCategoriesButton
          : styles.activeCategoriesButton
      }
      onPress={() => {
        getNewsByCategory(tagName);
        chooseCategory(!selectedCategory);
      }}>
      <Text style={styles.activeCategoriesButtonText}>{tagName}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default Tags;
```

In total it renders 5 tags from array.
When I click on one of the tags its state is changing to true how it is supposed to but the problem is, when I click on the another tag the state of previous tag is not being changed to false,Any suggestions on how can I achieve it please?

Answer (score 3):

The solution i would go with is saving wich 'Tag' is selected by their key where you also map them, then add something like 'isSelected' as a prop wich is true for you the one you selected.

Something like:

```
   const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState();

   const getNewsByCategory = (tagName) => {
     setSelectedCategory(tagName);
     //whatever you were doing here before
   }

   {activeNewsCategories.map((i) => (
                <Tags
                  key={i}
                  tagName={i}
                  isSelected={selectedCategory === i}
                  getNewsByCategory={getNewsByCategory}
                />
   ))}
```

And then change the

```
  const [selectedCategory, chooseCategory] = useState(false);
```

in the Tags to

```
  const [selectedCategory, chooseCategory] = tagName
```